# Java Send Encrypted Text from Client through Socket using RSA and Decrypt it in the Server

Tags: java, rsa

I have been trying to implement RSA encryption in a very simple client-server Java application.

To try and understand how the encryption works, I made my own scenario:

1. Alice (Server) wants to send a message to Bob (Client).
2. When Bob connects to Alice, they exchange public keys (e, n).
3. Once they have exchanged public keys, Alice encrypts the message "Hello!" with Bob's public key and sends it to Bob.
4. Bob receives the encrypted message and decrypts it using his private key (d, n).

This all makes sense to me, but when I tried to implement it in Java I'm getting inconsistent results. Sometimes I'd get a `NegativeArrayException`, or `ArithmeticException: BigInteger would overflow supported range`, and I have never decrypted the String successfully.

Here is my implementation:

**RSA.java**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class RSA {
    private BigInteger n;
    private BigInteger d;
    private BigInteger e;

    private PrivateKey privateKey;
    private PublicKey publicKey;

    public static class PublicKey {
        public byte[] getE() {
            return e;
        }

        public byte[] getN() {
            return n;
        }

        private final byte[] e;
        private final byte[] n;

        public PublicKey(byte[] e, byte[] n) {
            this.e = e;
            this.n = n;
        }
    }

    public static class PrivateKey {
        public byte[] getD() {
            return d;
        }
        public byte[] getN() {
            return n;
        }
        private final byte[] d;
        private final byte[] n;

        public PrivateKey(byte[] n, byte[] d) {
            this.n = n;
            this.d = d;
        }
    }

    public RSA() {
        generateKeyPair(1024);
    }

    public RSA(int bits) {
        generateKeyPair(bits);
    }

    public final void generateKeyPair(int bits) {

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        BigInteger p = new BigInteger(bits/2, 100, random);
        BigInteger q = new BigInteger(bits/2, 100, random);
        BigInteger phi = (p.subtract(new BigInteger("1"))).multiply(q.subtract(new BigInteger("1")));

        n = p.multiply(q);
        e = new BigInteger("3");


        while (phi.gcd(e).intValue() > 1) {
            e = e.add(new BigInteger("2"));
        }

        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println(n.toString());

        d = e.modInverse(phi);
        publicKey = new PublicKey(e.toByteArray(), n.toByteArray());
        privateKey = new PrivateKey(d.toByteArray(), n.toByteArray());
    }


    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainData, PublicKey publicKey) {
        return ((new BigInteger(plainData)).modPow(new BigInteger(publicKey.getE()), new BigInteger(publicKey.getN()))).toByteArray();
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedData) {
        return ((new BigInteger(encryptedData)).modPow(d, n)).toByteArray();
    }

    // (d, n)
    public PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
        return privateKey;
    }

    // (e, n)
    public PublicKey getPublicKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }
}
```

**Alice.java**

```
import crypto.RSA.PublicKey;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Alice {
    private final RSA encryption;
    public Alice() {
        encryption = new RSA();

        try {
            ServerSocket alice = new ServerSocket(2424);

            while(true) {
                Socket bob = alice.accept();

                DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(bob.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(bob.getOutputStream());

                byte[] bobE = new byte[1];
                byte[] bobN = new byte[inputStream.readInt()];

                // Read Bob's Public Key to encrypt Alice's Message.
                inputStream.read(bobE);
                inputStream.read(bobN);

                PublicKey bobPublicKey = new PublicKey(bobE, bobN);

                byte[] aliceE = encryption.getPublicKey().getE();
                byte[] aliceN = encryption.getPublicKey().getN();

                // Send Alice's Public Key to Bob just in case he wants to send Alice a message.
                outputStream.writeInt(aliceN.length); // N length
                outputStream.write(aliceE, 0, aliceE.length);
                outputStream.write(aliceN, 0, aliceN.length);   

                outputStream.flush();

                String messageToBob = "Hello!";

                byte[] encryptedMessage = encryption.encrypt(messageToBob.getBytes(), bobPublicKey);

                outputStream.writeInt(encryptedMessage.length);
                outputStream.write(encryptedMessage, 1, encryptedMessage.length-1);

                outputStream.flush();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

**Bob.java**

```
import crypto.RSA.PublicKey;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Bob {
    private final RSA encryption;
    public Bob() {
        encryption = new RSA();

        try {
            Socket alice = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2424);

            DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(alice.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(alice.getOutputStream());

            // Send Bob's public E and N to Alice.
            byte[] bobE = encryption.getPublicKey().getE();
            byte[] bobN = encryption.getPublicKey().getN();

            outputStream.writeInt(bobN.length); // N length
            outputStream.write(bobE, 0, bobE.length);
            outputStream.write(bobN, 0, bobN.length);
            outputStream.flush();

            byte[] aliceE = new byte[1];
            byte[] aliceN = new byte[inputStream.readInt()];

            // Read Alice's public key. (unused)
            inputStream.read(aliceE);
            inputStream.read(aliceN);

            PublicKey alicePublicKey = new PublicKey(aliceE, aliceN);

            // Read Alice's Message Size.
            int encryptedMessageSize = inputStream.readInt();

            byte[] encryptedMessageFromAlice = new byte[encryptedMessageSize];

            // Read Alice's Message.
            // Here is where everything goes wrong.
            inputStream.read(encryptedMessageFromAlice, 1, encryptedMessageSize-1);

            System.out.println("Got a message from alice (" + encryptedMessageFromAlice.length + "): ");
            System.out.println(new String(encryption.decrypt(encryptedMessageFromAlice)));

        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

**Main method**

```
(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Alice alice = new Alice();

    }
}).start();

Bob bob = new Bob();
```

I feel like I may be missing some fundamentals, but I've read how it works, checked out examples (all of them incomplete, though), and I don't see where the mistake is.

I know there are libraries that make this much easier, but I need to learn the basic implementation of it, using BigInteger.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:** 
I have made the length of the moduli non-hardcoded as James said.

After running the program, here is what is printed out (the message is always the same "Hello!"):

**Try 1**

```
Got a message from alice (41): 
N�qpfcc�d�����J��
�$P�m�1�qj?��K�����s�����IQ@��g�u�)^���\m"ݒ�M��7p�}�!����
```

**Try 2**

```
Got a message from alice (41): 
W��LW\t� b�w��P�3Ꟊ��?�g��ϔSx�N���<Vx� �ĝJ:h1��ޟ�KY�:vtad��0\R-�ǰ���3D4~_�
~���Cy�$$y��#{�^U$;՞�RU��ݘN�C'0��S
```

**Try 3**

```
Got a message from alice (18): 
Rq���ҞlapZ�L����t�,��@k��&��=�.o�� ��   ��������؉I�g>+h��ʸz��=��l���a��+�\Gഢ��ccn�n�1[1���Bu�A�]    �n�b�Tu�o!
```

Comment: You are assuming that the moduli will always be 128 bytes, but that's incorrect. They will often be 129 bytes. There's no reason to hard-code those values, just write the length followed by that many bytes just like you do with the encrypted values.

Comment: What James said. In addition 'textbook' (unpadded) RSA is badly insecure and usually easily broken; non-CRT RSA is costlier for no benefit. See wikipedia, or dozens of existing Qs on crypto.SX and security.SX.

Comment: Understood. I am required to do the 'textbook' implementation of RSA, though. It's not going to be used for anything serious.

I have added the moduli length as James has said.
Any idea why the decrypted message is coming out like this?

`Got a message from alice (41): 
N�qpfcc�d�����J��
�$P�m�1�qj?��K�����s�����IQ@��g�u�)^���\m"ݒ�M��7p�}�!����`

Comment: Tip 1: never ignore the return value from `InputStream.read()`. Tip 2: Since you are using DataInputStream, take advantage of `DataInputStream.readFully()`. No return value to worry about!

Comment: @DerrickC. Were you able to fix it? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Any up here ? I faced the same issue :)